# "Infinitely" high data transfer with Golang TCP connection on localhost

Tags: go, networking

### Problem

I have written a TCP echo server in Go and I am trying to write/read as often as I can in 10s to measure how much data got transfered in this time. Weirdly, the value is way too high and does not depend on the length of the bytearray which I am transfering (but it should!). It is always around 600k connections in this 10 seconds (The length of the "result" Array depicts how much connections were made in the 10s). As soon as I add let's say a print statement to the server and the values get processed, I get more realistic values that depend on the length of the bytearray as a result.
Why doesn't the length of the bytearray matter in the first case?

### Code

#### Server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {

    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("127.0.0.1:8888"))
    checkError(err)

    ln, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        checkError(err)

        go handleConnection(conn)
    }
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    var input [1000000]byte

    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(input[0:])
        checkError(err)

        //fmt.Println(input[0:n])

        _, err = conn.Write(input[0:n])
        checkError(err)
    }

}
```

#### Client

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

var (
    result  []int
    elapsed time.Duration
)

func main() {
    input := make([]byte, 1000)

    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8888")
    checkError(err)

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)

    for start := time.Now(); time.Since(start) < time.Second*time.Duration(10); {

        startTimer := time.Now()
        _, err = conn.Write(input)
        checkError(err)

        _, err := conn.Read(input[0:])
        checkError(err)

        elapsed = time.Since(startTimer)
        result = append(result, int(elapsed))

    }

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("result: %v", len(result)))

}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are connecting once and reading/writing many times. You are not connecting many times.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. I meant write/read as often as I can in 10s on the one server.

Comment: You are communicating with a server on localhost. You are essentially measuring memory copy speed. Try with a host on another host.

Comment: Just tested your code locally with a 1000 byte array and get around 450k calls. If I go up to 1000000 byte array I get only ~18k calls through. So... seems it works in principle. Not sure what happens on your computer if that is not the case for you... The Go code itself seems good though.

Comment: @TehSphinX You are right. If I drastically increase the number, the rate seems to change. But I still think this probably is memory copy speed because in my case (1000000 length), I get ~58k calls. That would be 5Gb/s which rather seems to be memory copy speed to me.

Comment: Yes, definitely. localhost to localhost is not the correct scenario if you want to measure real network speed.

Comment: But note also: If you want to benchmark server speed, you can't do that with a single client. Unless single client throughput is what you want to benchmark. It depends a bit what you want to benchmark. If you want server speed benchmarks, you need multiple clients or simulate them with goroutines. Then you should also consider that the client(s) will use up CPU if you run it on the same system as the server -- especially if you use hundreds or thousands of goroutines.

Comment: @TehSphinX I want to benchmark a custom net package implementation designed for tinyGo. So I just wanted some data on how long it took the net package to respond and then compare it to the custom one.

Answer (score 0):

`Read` in the client loop is not guaranteed to read all of the data sent in the previous call to `Write`.

When `input` is small enough to be transmitted in a single packet on the network, `Read` in the client returns all of the data in the previous call to `Write` in the client.  In this mode, the application measures the time to execute request/response pairs.

For larger sizes of `input`, read on the client can fall behind what the client is writing. When this happens, the calls to `Read` complete faster because the calls return data from an earlier call to `Write`. The application is pipelining in this mode.  The throughput for pipelining is higher than the throughput for request/response pairs. The client will not read all data in this mode, but the timing impact of that is not significant.

Use the following code to time request/response pairs for arbitrary sizes of `input`.

```
for start := time.Now(); time.Since(start) < time.Second*time.Duration(10); {
    startTimer := time.Now()
    _, err = conn.Write(input)
    checkError(err)

    _, err := io.ReadFull(conn, input) // <-- read all of the data
    checkError(err)

    elapsed = time.Since(startTimer)
    result = append(result, int(elapsed))
}
```

To measure full-on pipelining, modify the client to read and write from different goroutines. An example follows.

```
go func() {
    for start := time.Now(); time.Since(start) < time.Second*time.Duration(10); {
        _, err = conn.Write(input)
        checkError(err)
    }
    conn.CloseWrite() // tell server that we are done sending data
}()

start := time.Now()

output := make([]byte, 4096)
for {
    _, err := conn.Read(output)
    if err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        checkError(err)
    }
}

fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
```

Comment: While this is correct, the data will be there the next call to read. So the data does get read and written back "eventually". But definitely not production ready code, for sure!

Comment: @TehSphinX There's no guarantee that the client reads all of the data. The number of reads is equal to the number of writes.  There's no guarantee that that a read slurps up all of the data from the previous write.  It follows that there's no guarantee that the client reads all of the data.

Comment: If the data is available it will be read until the target slice is full. There is no quaranty that the data is already available therefore you are right: the data written in the last call(s) is not guaranteed to ever be read. It does not really affect this benchmark though.

Comment: @TehSphinX It does affect the timing because reads are quickly satisfied from earlier writes.